# What happened to CompleteAsync and AbandonAsync method for ServiceBusTriggers in Azure Functions 2.0

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I could implement something similar to the following in Azure Functions 1.0, but now it seems with 2.0 `CompleteAsync()` and `AbandonAsync()` are no longer available.

```
[FunctionName("Process")]
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(
        "%ServiceBus.Topic%", "%ServiceBus.Subscription%",
        Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]Message message, ILogger log) {
    try {
        MyMessageModel messageModel = message.GetBody<MyMessageModel>();
        await DoAllTheThingsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);                
        await message.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    } catch {
        await message.AbandonAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Has control been relinquished to the [Azure Function default for Peek Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Function 1.X used [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) library for processing message. There, the methods like `CompleteAsync()` and `AbandonAsync()` were available with the [BrokeredMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?view=azure-dotnet) object received by the Function.

Where in Functions of version 2.X, [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus?view=azure-dotnet) library is being used, here BrokeredMessage is replaced by [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet) object, where no such methods are available. They are available only under [QueueClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.ireceiverclient.abandonasync?view=azure-dotnet